# How to storage de data of an array and then mark a checbox when the checbox is mark on the google forms?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-forms, storing-data

To give you some context I'm automatazing a google forms to send a pdf file to a certain gmail, everytime is sent, the problem is with the arrays that I have in my code is not filling the checboxes when I mark them in my google forms. Here you can see the code:
Here is the array:

```
var pertenenciasCocinas = {
    cafeteraElectrica: respuestas['Cafetera electrica'] == 'Sí',
    licuadora: respuestas['Licuadora'] == 'Sí',
    botellonAgua: respuestas['Botellón de agua'] == 'Sí',
    cubiertos: respuestas['Cubiertos'] == 'Sí',
    microondas: respuestas['Microondas'] == 'Sí',
    nevera: respuestas['Nevera'] == 'Sí',
    jarronCristal: respuestas['Jarrón de cristal'] == 'Sí',
    tablaPicar: respuestas['Tabla de picar.'] == 'Sí',
    grecaCafetera: respuestas['Greca o cafetera'] == 'Sí',
    setCocina: respuestas['Set de cocina'] == 'Sí'
  };
```

And here is the code for the checboxes:

```
  if (pertenenciasCocinas.cafeteraElectrica) {
    body.replaceText("{{CafeteraElectricacotejo}}", "☑");
  } else {
    body.replaceText("{{CafeteraElectricacotejo}}", "☐");
  }
  if (pertenenciasCocinas.licuadora) {
    body.replaceText("{{Licuadoracotejo}}", "☑");
  } else {
    body.replaceText("{{Licuadoracotejo}}", "☐");
  }
  if (pertenenciasCocinas.botellonAgua) {
    body.replaceText("{{BotellonAguaCotejo}}", "☑");
  } else {
    body.replaceText("{{BotellonAguaCotejo}}", "☐");
  }
  if (pertenenciasCocinas.cubiertos) {
    body.replaceText("{{CubiertosCotejo}}", "☑");
  } else {
  body.replaceText("{{CubiertosCotejo}}", "☐");
  }
  if (pertenenciasCocinas.microondas) {
  body.replaceText("{{MicroondasCotejo}}", "☑");
  } else {
  body.replaceText("{{MicroondasCotejo}}", "☐");
  }
  if (pertenenciasCocinas.nevera) {
  body.replaceText("{{NeveraCotejo}}", "☑");
  } else {
  body.replaceText("{{NeveraCotejo}}", "☐");
  }
  if (pertenenciasCocinas.jarronCristal) {
  body.replaceText("{{JarronCristalCotejo}}", "☑");
  } else {
  body.replaceText("{{JarronCristalCotejo}}", "☐");
  }
  if (pertenenciasCocinas.tablaPicar) {
  body.replaceText("{{TablaPicarCotejo}}", "☑");
  } else {
  body.replaceText("{{TablaPicarCotejo}}", "☐");
  }
  if (pertenenciasCocinas.grecaCafetera) {
  body.replaceText("{{GrecaCafeteraCotejo}}", "☑");
  } else {
  body.replaceText("{{GrecaCafeteraCotejo}}", "☐");
  }
  if (pertenenciasCocinas.setCocina) {
  body.replaceText("{{SetCocinaCotejo}}", "☑");
  } else {
  body.replaceText("{{SetCocinaCotejo}}", "☐");
  }
```

Sorry that the code is in spanish.

I tried to play around with the way im storing things in the array, but I didn't knew how to fix it.

Comment: Google Form does not interact with Google Apps Script until submission is made.

Comment: I mean yes but I submited a couple times and still the checkbox it was empty

Comment: "I mean yes but I submited a couple times and still the checkbox it was empty ". You need to provide a description of your scenario (leave nothing out), is this the only script, what triggers the script?, explain the purpose function of the checkboxes (that is not obvious), etc. Start at the beginning and leave nothing out.